# Filter product with less than two categories

Tags: api, category, filter

My SOAP api script should list products that are in one or none categories. 
I don't know how filter works with category_ids:

```
$filters = array(
    'category_ids' => array('like'=>'???')
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are 2 category ids there should be a comma between them. So you can try this:

```
$filters = array(
    'category_ids' => array('nlike'=>'%,%')
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

But I'm not sure this will work since the `category_ids` attribute was dropped in the upgrade file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.33-1.4.0.0.34.php`.

```
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'category_ids');
```

It may depend on the version you have.

Answer (score 0):

category_ids doesn't work with product.list from magento 1.4 anymore. Try to use 'catalog_category.assignedProducts'.

```
$productList = $proxy->call($sessionId, ‘catalog_category.assignedProducts’, array(’4’));
```

And after you will have all product ids use 'catalog_product.list'.